# Is this the correct way to stop and execute my sub again?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

i get strange debug info when running my code below, basically there are conditions that are met when executing the code but then when it stops and i debug it, these conditions are not met and it should not have stopped.

I have a doubt about my first IF statement in my code. Basically i'm checking if a condition is met (receive "message" in my json data, and if it is met, i want to stop and start my sub (Trades) again.

Is this the correct way to do this ?

```
    Sub Trades()

Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
MyRequest.Open "GET", "https://api.gdax.com/products/ETH-EUR/trades"
MyRequest.Send

Set ParsedTrades = JsonConverter.ParseJson(MyRequest.ResponseText)

'to try to fight intermitent bug
Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(19, "U") = MyRequest.ResponseText
WaitTime (2)

'check if did not receive error string from exchange, if so, start again (i should add logger here)
Dim pos As Integer
pos = InStr(MyRequest.ResponseText, "message")
If pos > 0 Then
Trades
End If

    'to speed up execution when looping
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

For i = 1 To 100

        'check if new tradeid > last tradeid, if so, copy
        LastTradeId = Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(2, "B")
        If ParsedTrades(i)("trade_id") > LastTradeId Then

            Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(i + 1, 15) = ParsedTrades(i)("time")
            Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(i + 1, 16) = ParsedTrades(i)("trade_id")
            Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(i + 1, 17) = ParsedTrades(i)("price")
            Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(i + 1, 18) = ParsedTrades(i)("size")
            Workbooks("GDAX Order book and trades.xlsm").Sheets("trades").Cells(i + 1, 19) = ParsedTrades(i)("side")

        End If
```

Comment: `If CLng(ParsedTrades(i)("trade_id")) > CLng(LastTradeId) Then` or something like that but you don't include your variable declarations so it's difficult to tell if that's the problem. Also your JSON URL returns an "Under maintenance" message so there's no knowing what's in your returned dataset.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your feed-back. That LastTradeId = ... line never gave me any problems. It's on the very next line that it kicks me out because sometimes i receive an error message from the server and my first IF statement should have caught it (according to debug info) but for some reasons the code still goes into the second IF statement instead of starting my sub again. So my question is : is this the correct way to stop my first IF statement and start my Sub again ? If it is, then my problem is elsewhere.

Comment: and yes the server is down for maintenance but it is just a coincidence.

Comment: you need to  break your `Trades` sub into atleast two subs. One like `FetchTrade` where you send the query, get the response and validate it. if its valid then send it to another sub 'ProcessTrade` for processing.

Comment: ok, i will split it. But still, i would like to know if it is ok to get out of my first IF and branch back to the beginning of the sub. I might not need it anymore, but Im still curious to know.

Comment: ok, i ve added the Exit Sub line , witout splitting my code yet, and it s been running without the error for 2 hours now, looks like it was the problem. I have up voted the answer, altough it tells me it won t display publicly as i m a newbie, but thanks a lot for the feed'back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Dim pos As Integer
pos = InStr(MyRequest.ResponseText, "message")
If pos > 0 Then
    'Error: wait a couple of seconds and then try again
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "Trades"
    Exit Sub
End If
```